Delaunay Triangulation but in 3D
I guess this is the right place to ask this question. Let me tell you why did I ask this question, so I have a pointcloud data that I want to calculate it's volume, I know that pointcloud lib has something such as poisson, hull to calc it's volume, but it's not that accurate, so I found an algorithm called Delaunay Triangulation, and I managed to implement it in 2D and visualize it's process with OpenCV. But when I go to 3D, I am really confused on how to implement it, process, and equations, I managed to did it as well (knowing the triangles in 3d is tetrahedrons). But the volume that I was calculating is incorrect, and some of the tetrahedrons are intercepting each other, is there anyone that know how to fix this issue or know the steps, or maybe the equation?
PS: I'm new in this stack, so sorry if something wrong with my question
